# Find the acceleration of a block sliding down on an accelerating inclined place

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity, free-body-diagram

[image]

I don't understand the solution provided in the image. Using Newton's second law for forces along the x-axis (parallel to the inclined plane), shouldn't the equation be $ma = mg\sin \theta+ mb\cos \theta$?

Comment: [Homework](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714) questions are off topic here. Thanks.

Comment: The acceleration a is relative to the inclined block, not relative to an inertial frame of reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The acceleration $\mathbf a$ is referred in the frame of the inclined plane.

\begin{align}
  \mathbf b &= b\cos \theta \, \mathbf i+b\sin \theta \, \mathbf j \\
  \mathbf g &= g\sin \theta \, \mathbf i-g\cos \theta \, \mathbf j \\
  m\, \mathbf g+R\, \mathbf j &= m(\mathbf a + \mathbf b) \\
\end{align}

Isolating the $\mathbf j$ component gives the result immediately.